# Vim: Display similar snippets in a highly efficient manner

Tags: search, vim, plugins, grep

**Summary**

- Is there a "find similar snippets" plugin is available for VIM, OR ALTERNATIVELY,
- is there a plugin for vim which could easily be extended to do this efficiently?

**Details**

I realize this is a strange question to ask without context, so here is the context.  I'm open to other solutions to the same problem if a "vim plugin" isn't ideal.

I generally do **a lot of grepping** when working on a new project.  Is there a way inside of vim, that i can **"grep" and display several snippets (the 2 lines above/below)**  for a particular string which im currently highlighting.

**Clarification:** For example, in this post, If i highlighted "inside of vim", I'd like to see (in the VIM window) the results of *grep -r -B 2 -A 2 "inside of vim"*.

The hard part here is of course (1) the visualization pop up and (2) having the shortcut to type when text is selected, otherwise its easy to grep for this kind of thing in a separate terminal.  **I generally find "CTRL+N" is VERY useful largely because the 2nd dimension it adds for auto-completion, and im mostly looking for an extension of it which shows a glimpse of similar code snippets in other files of a directory.**

Comment: Have you tried `:vimgrep` and/or `:grep`? (You'll need to manually open the `quickfix` window for `:grep` I believe, with `:copen`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin.  Try it, you'll be impressed.

On a side note, [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) can make use of [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) and [ag](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/).  These are essentially improved versions of `grep`, tuned up for programming.  Take a look at those too, they will change your programming life for the better.

There are also [Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) and [Ag](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) plugins that can interface Vim with [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) and [ag](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) directly, which work by putting the output of said programs in quickfix lists.  However, [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) does all that and much more.

Comment: this worked, spectacular!  Wrote a blog post on how i set up my dev environment and the plugins I'm using (CtrlSF, NerdTree) http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2015/07/java-developer-seeking-awesome-dev.html